# 1072 - Key column 'trax_zone_id' doesn't exist in table

Tags: mysql

this is the parent table

```
CREATE TABLE trax_zone(
    trax_zone_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    trax_zone_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,

)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

this is the child table code

```
CREATE TABLE city(
    city_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    city_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY fk_trax(trax_zone_id) REFERENCES trax_zone(trax_zone_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    FOREIGN KEY fk_zoop(zoop_zone_id) REFERENCES zoop_zone(zoop_zone_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT   
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

i am new to mysql , kindly guide me

Comment: Neither tax_zone_id or zoop_zone_id exist in the table CITY so the error is as expected.And you don't have a table called zoop_zone. I've never heard of these terms and cannot guess their purpose.

Comment: okay ! i got it.....i miss understand. thank you so much!